# What is the fragment that represent an item in a json schema links array

Tags: jsonschema

Given the following two JSON Schema definitions

**Schema A**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
  "title": "Member Resource",
  "description": "A Member at a group",
  "id": "schemata/member",
  "definitions": {
    "first_name": {
      "description": "the first name",
      "example": "Severus",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 255,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "description": "the last name",
      "example": "Snape",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 255,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "member_response": {
      "description": "Successful response to a show or search request",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "member": { "$ref": "/schemata/member" }
      },
      "required": ["member"]
    },
    "error_response": {
      "description": "Error response to a show or search request",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "reference_id": {"$ref": "#/definitions/reference_id"},
        "errors": {"$ref": "#/definitions/errors"}
      },
      "required": [errors"]
    }
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "description": "Retrieve a member",
      "href": "/members/{(%23%2Fschemata%member%2Fdefinitions%2Fidentity)}",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "instance",
      "title": "Show",
      "targetSchema": {
         "description": "Result of a get request. Can be either a success or a failure.",
         "type": ["object"],
         "oneOf": [
           { "$ref": "#/definitions/member_response" },
           { "$ref": "#/definitions/error_response" }
         ]
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "Search for a member",
      "href": "/members/search",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "instance",
      "schema": {
        "description": "The expected payload for a search request",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "first_name": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/first_name"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/last_name"
          }
        },
        "required": ["first_name", "last_name"]
      },
      "targetSchema": {
         "description": "Result of a get request. Can be either a success or a failure.",
         "type": ["object"],
         "oneOf": [
           { "$ref": "#/definitions/member_response" },
           { "$ref": "#/definitions/error_response" }
         ]
      }
      "title": "Search"
    }
  ],
}
```

**Schema B**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
  "title": "Member Resource",
  "description": "A Member at a group",
  "id": "schemata/member",
  "definitions": {
    "first_name": {
      "description": "the first name",
      "example": "Severus",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 255,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "description": "the last name",
      "example": "Snape",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 255,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "search_payload": {
      "description": "The expected payload for a search request",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/first_name"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/last_name"
        }
      },
      "required": ["first_name", "last_name"]
    },
    "member_response": {
      "description": "Successful response to a show or search request",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "member": { "$ref": "/schemata/member" }
      },
      "required": ["member"]
    },
    "error_response": {
      "description": "Error response to a show or search request",
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "reference_id": {"$ref": "#/definitions/reference_id"},
        "errors": {"$ref": "#/definitions/errors"}
      },
      "required": [errors"]
    },
    "get_response": {
      "description": "Result of a get request. Can be either a success or a failure.",
      "type": ["object"],
      "oneOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/member_response" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/error_response" }
      ]
    }
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "description": "Retrieve a member",
      "href": "/members/{(%23%2Fschemata%member%2Fdefinitions%2Fidentity)}",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "instance",
      "title": "Show",
      "targetSchema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/get_response"
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "Search for a member",
      "href": "/members/search",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "instance",
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/search_payload"
      },
      "targetSchema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/get_response"
      },
      "title": "Search"
    }
  ],
}
```

Both schemas are functionally the same. The difference is that `targetSchema` is defined inline in schema **A** but as a ref in schema **B**.

I use a library to validate the input and output to and API endpoint. For example when testing my APIs I want to validate that the response to each request returns a JSON object that conforms with `targetSchema` for that API.

```
JSON::Validator.fully_validate(
  schema,
  object_to_test,
  :fragment => "/path/to/fragment"
)
```

In order to validate against the `targetSchema` for the /members/search API defined above I need to be able to reference its `targetSchema`.

In schema **B** I can do

```
JSON::Validator.fully_validate(
  schema,
  object_to_test,
  :fragment => "#/definitions/get_response"
)
```

Is it possible to do the above for schema **A** too? i.e. can I reference the actual `targetSchema` of the search link directly. Perhaps it might look like the following

```
JSON::Validator.fully_validate(
  schema,
  object_to_test,
  :fragment => "#/links[1]/targetSchema"
)
```

or

```
JSON::Validator.fully_validate(
  schema,
  object_to_test,
  :fragment => "#/links/[SOME_WAY_OF_SPECIFYING_THAT_TITLA_EQL_SEARCH"]/targetSchema"
)
```

Comment: I'm always glad to see people using JSON Hyper-Schema.  I would really like to help, but I can't make heads or tails of your question.  Is there more you can add to the question to help clarify what you are trying to accomplish?  Maybe an example?

Comment: Of course. Let me try to restate it.

Comment: Ahh, I see now.  The question is how to construct a JSON Pointer that points to an element in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your schema, you can reference the search link's `targetSchema` with the following JSON Pointer(1).

```
#/links/1/targetSchema
```

Here `1` is the index of the desired item in the links array.  This is the only way to reference an item in an array.  To precisely answer the question -- there is no way of specifying the item in the array where `title` equals "search".

Obviously, referencing the `targetSchema` using an index is fragile.  If you add a link to the schema in the wrong place, your code will break.  You would be better off if you looped through the links in code and chose the one you need.

You might ask, "Why is it so difficult to reference a link's `targetSchema` for validation?"  The answer is that `targetSchema` is not intended for validation.  `targetSchema` is intended to be informational only.  It's documentation.  The only schema that the response should be responsible for conforming to is the one it declares in the response(2).  This is one of the core ideas of REST.  The client and server are decoupled.  The client doesn't make any assumptions about the response it will get.  The response itself should have all the information needed to interpret the response and what you can do next.

1. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901
2. http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor33

Comment: Thanks Jason. The "why is it so hard" question/answer is valid. I simply use this in our automated test suite to ensure our endpoints conform with the schema. This ensures that we update our schema before  (or at least at the same time) we modify our API. Perhaps this is an anti-pattern but it has been useful.